# Unable to add Microsoft Service Bus API in Azure App Registration

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

From various tutorials and stack overflow questions, I see a possibility to add Service Bus in the API Permission tab of an App Registration in Azure. See image below.

[image: sample]

However, I don't see this option in my organization's or my personal Azure tenant now. Has this been taken off by Microsoft recently? Are you able to see an option to add Service Bus?

Comment: I cannot find the permission either in my org but it may be related to this setting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/disable-local-authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I couldn't able to see Microsoft Service bus api permissions as below:

[image]

But check the similar functionality by giving `azure service bus data owner` role which has the similar functionality using below process:

Firstly, go to your Resource group and then click on Access Control:

[image]

Next click on Add+:

[image]

Then type Service Bus:

[image]

Then Select your required App Registration and then click on select:

[image]

Now Click ON Access Control and check you have got your required permission On Service Bus:

[image]

Now click on it:

[image]

If you your access is denied adding role assignment, then you need to ask you admin to provide you the access.

And also check [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/disable-local-authentication).